# Prevent temporary instantiation of class

Tags: c++, c++17

How can I prevent instantiation of temporary instances of a certain class?

I've tried creating a method which can be called upon lvalue instances only and calling that method in the c'tor to prevent rvalue instantiations of the class in compile-time, but it didn't help -- the method was called successfully even for rvalue instantiations of the class. It seems that the c'tor is oblivious to the fact that it's currently constructing an rvalue instance; lvalue-only method calls are allowed either way.

My goal is to create a scoped guard for allocations returned by *WinApi*, which must be freed via `LocalFree`.
I want to prevent from temporary instances of the class, which would cause immediate deallocation of the allocation, defeating the purpose of being a **scoped** guard.
This might also cause unpredictable runtime behavior, because memory freed by `LocalFree` might still be accessible for some time after the function call.

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] of what you've tried and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @golosovsky So you want to protect against accidentally doing `T(...);` instead of `T foo(...);`? Then I suggest making a macro to create scope guards (which can't be misused). Or adding `[[nodiscard]]` either to the whole class or to the constructor.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's currently the most suitable answer. But it has it's obvious drawbacks: it's supported only on c++17 and higher and it produces a warning, not an error (it's not that trivial to switch to "treat warning as error" in a large project). Anyway, regarding my case -- it's pretty simple. I want to avoid an edge case where the WinApi-allocated memory is wrapped in a temp-instance of the wrap-class which will cause it to be freed immediately. This might cause unpredictable runtime behavior, because memory freed by `LocalFree` might still be accessible for some time after the call.

Comment: Why does "_memory freed by `LocalFree` might still be accessible for some time after the call_" worry you? You have a similar situation when you `delete[]` something.

Comment: Due to the fact that it might lead to undefined behavior -- I'd love to get rid of the uncertainty and to enforce the "correct" behavior in compile time, to avoid potential nondeterministic runtime issues.

Comment: @golosovsky Why would it lead to undefined behavior? Even if `delete[]` doesn't actually return the memory to the OS and remove it from what's available to your process, it doesn't lead to undefined behavior. Only if you try to access it will you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @golosovsky I agree, `[[nodiscard]]` has drawbacks. But what about using a macro to create the scope guard?

Comment: Have you considered throwing in a move constructor instead?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the question correctly, you should be fine with a RAII wrapper around your resource.

Here's an outline of how that could look:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class [[nodiscard]] ScopedAlloc {
public:
    ScopedAlloc(UINT uFlags, SIZE_T elems) : 
        hRes(LocalAlloc(uFlags, elems*sizeof(T)))
    {
        if (hRes == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("ScopedAlloc failed " +
                                     std::to_string(GetLastError()));
    }

    // A constructor to take ownership of a HLOCAL created with LocalAlloc
    explicit ScopedAlloc(HLOCAL res) : hRes(res) {
        if(LocalSize(hRes) == 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("ScopedAlloc failed " +
                                     std::to_string(GetLastError()));
    }

    ScopedAlloc(const ScopedAlloc&) = delete; // or let it allocate and copy
    ScopedAlloc(ScopedAlloc&& rhs) : hRes(std::exchange(rhs.hRes, nullptr)) {}
    ScopedAlloc& operator=(const ScopedAlloc&) = delete; // or LocalReAlloc and copy
    ScopedAlloc& operator=(ScopedAlloc&& rhs) {
        std::swap(hRes, rhs.hRes);
        return *this;
    }

    ~ScopedAlloc() {
#ifndef NDEBUG
        if (hRes) { // fill memory with garbage in debug mode
            SIZE_T size = LocalSize(hRes);
            if (size) std::memset(hRes, 0xdd, size); // 0xDD - Dead Memory pattern
        }
#endif
        LocalFree(hRes);
    }

    operator const T* () const { return static_cast<T*>(hRes); }
    operator T* () { return static_cast<T*>(hRes); }

private:
    HLOCAL hRes;
};
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

struct bar { int x, y; };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bar& b) {
    return os << '{' << b.x << ',' << b.y << '}';
}

int main() {
    ScopedAlloc<bar> foo(LMEM_FIXED | LMEM_ZEROINIT, 2);
    foo[0] = {1, 2};
    foo[1] = {3, 4};
    std::cout << foo[0] << ", " << foo[1] << '\n';    // prints   {1,2}, {3,4}
}
```

Comment: It's a perfectly fine RAII wrap for a Windows local-allocations, but the class doesn't prohibit temporary instantiation. Which means, I can do the following: `ScopedAlloc<bar>(LMEM_FIXED | LMEM_ZEROINIT, 2);` and it will be perfectly fine, which defeats the purpose of my question. As I stated in the question, the actual use case is: I get a `LocalAlloc` allocated piece of memory by WinApi and I want to wrap it with such wrapper which allow access to it throughout the current scope and call `LocalFree` upon it on scope-end.

Comment: @golosovsky Ok, I don't understand the case then. Wouldn't `[[nodiscard]]` like [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) suggested solve that?

Comment: Yes, it's currently the most suitable answer. But it has it's obvious drawbacks: it's supported only on c++17 and higher and it produces a warning, not an error (it's not that trivial to switch to "treat warning as error" in a large project). Anyway, regarding my case -- it's pretty simple. I want to avoid an edge case where the WinApi-allocated memory is wrapped in a temp-instance of the wrap-class which will cause it to be freed immediately. This might cause unpredictable runtime behavior, because memory freed by `LocalFree` might still be accessible for some time after the call.

Comment: @golosovsky I still don't get it. You want to prevent bad programming? If I saw `std::string("foo");` (which isn't even marked `[[nodiscard]]` in the standard library), I'd downvote that in a code review. Add `-Werror` (or similar) to turn warnings into errors. For earlier C++ versions, use compiler extensions instead of `[[nodiscard]]`, like `warn_unused_result` in gcc.

Comment: @golosovsky If I understand you correctly, you'd want `static_cast<void>(ScopedAlloc<bar>(LMEM_FIXED | LMEM_ZEROINIT, 2));` to fail to compile even though the programmer has explicitly showed that this temporary instance is exactly what he/she wants (for some obscure reason) because "_memory freed by `LocalFree` might still be accessible for some time after the call_"? What do you mean by "_still accessible_" exactly?

Comment: I've demonstrated my intention using your class, which isn't quite representative of the issue at hand -- it allocates memory upon construction, in contrast to the discussed scenario, where the pre-allocated addr is passed to the c'tot. Regarding your question on what I meant by _"might still be accessible"_ -- I don't know if it's a timing-dependent issue or OS build dependent (probably both), but in certain cases the memory supposed to be freed by `LocalFree` isn't immediately freed and the data is still accessible when the next opcodes are executed.

Comment: For example, in the next case, str construction behavior is undefined -- in some cases it will be constructed successfully and hold a copy the just-freed str, in other cases it's contents might be just garbage or the c'tor might fail:
`PVOID strPtr = nullptr;
SomeWinApiWhichAllocatesAndReturnsString(..., &strPtr);
AllocGuard(strPtr);
std::string str ((char*)strPtr);`

Comment: "_where the pre-allocated addr is passed to the c'tot_" - I added a ctor for that now. "_in certain cases the memory supposed to be freed by LocalFree isn't immediately freed_" - and how is this visible and how is that a problem? I don't understand the last comment about the strings. If the function returns a `LocalAlloc`ated resource, just give it to the ctor I added and it'll be free'd when it goes out of scope.

Comment: That's correct. In the example above, the line `AllocGuard(strPtr);` both constructs and destructs the object -- which means that `LocalFree` is called. The line `std::string str ((char*)strPtr);` which "logically" should cause some runtime error, in certain cases works just fine. On my Win 10, when I debug line-by-line, the memory isn't being overridden after the `LocalFree` call. I want to avoid such runtime scenarios. I can, of-course, just change the class' behavior to accept a ref to the ptr, which will allow me to nullify it upon destruction. But I prefer a compile-time enf. solution.

Comment: @golosovsky I've not seen the code for this `AllocGuard` or how you use it so I can't speak for what it's doing  or if you are using it wrong - or what `std::string str ((char*)strPtr);` is really supposed to do. It's a C type cast, but what would the C++ equivalent cast be? `std::string str(static_cast<char*>(strPtr));`? Do you have a conversion operator for `AllocGuard?  If so, `str` will make a copy of the null terminated C string, and if it's a proper C string, that won't be a problem as long as the owner does not free before `str` has copied.

Comment: Are you perhaps passing temporary that you don't reference as const and by that not prolonging the life of the temporary?